# Re-binding the expose key on a macbook

Tags: macos, osx-lion, hotkeys

The expose button on my macbook is absolutely useless to me as I use an application launcher. Is there some easy way to re-bind it to something more useful (like show desktop)? Or must I muck around with plists and the like to get anything done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/) to change it to F3. You can change it to another key with [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<item>
<name>test</name>
<identifier>private.test</identifier>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::EXPOSE_ALL, ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::EXPOSE_ALL, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
</item>
```

See the source for [predefined settings](https://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml) and other [key constants](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/tree/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data).